# Generating a perfect loop

Tags: loop, woocommerce-offtopic, wpdb

So I have been sitting here now for about three hours and I have to let this go for a few hours to grab some sleep while I hopefully get some help from you.

I have been able to get content from a database using $wpdb->get_results, and have been able to put them into an array, but I then want to use that information to run a new query inside a loop to fetch multiple items in a list.

I have used a variation of this guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848249/woocommerce-get-all-orders-for-a-product to get the order ids. Now that I have them in an array, I would like to loop the array without getting a duplicate first entry. This is my current code that works, but it gives a duplicate first entry.

```
foreach ($orders_ids as $details) {
  $paameldingid[]=$details->order_id;
  $i=0;
  while ($order_id = $paameldingid[$i]){
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$fornavn = $order->get_billing_first_name();
$etternavn = $order->get_billing_last_name();
$deltakerkategori = $order->get_meta( '_billing_field_447', true );
$deltakerradio = $order->get_meta( '_billing_field_538', true );
echo ''.$fornavn.' '.$etternavn.' '.$deltakerkategori.'/'.$deltakerradio.'<br>';
 $i++; 
 }
}
```

Working example: http://www.va24.no/paameldinger.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're looping twice due to the while. Completely unecessary.

```
foreach ($orders_ids as $details) {
    $order = wc_get_order($details->order_id);
    $fornavn = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $etternavn = $order->get_billing_last_name();
    $deltakerkategori = $order->get_meta( '_billing_field_447', true );
    $deltakerradio = $order->get_meta( '_billing_field_538', true );
    echo ''.$fornavn.' '.$etternavn.' '.$deltakerkategori.'/'.$deltakerradio.'<br>';
}
```

Additionally, if that doesn't fix it due to...well, magic, try this patch:

`foreach( array_unique( $order_ids ) as $details )`

But this smells. Bad. Check your data and see where it's going wrong.

Comment: That did it! Thank you, and by the way. This code might look messy, but it's a compact way to show a list of buyers of specific products in the shop. This site is using woocommerce as a registry for participants at a convention.

Comment: @skoen No problem. As for "compact", no, objectively speaking, it isn't. A function should only have one purpose. I see a lot of de-couple potential here, you're doing way too much in a single function for this to ever be used in any sane system.